# The maximum and minimum of a function

Tags: calculus

How can I find the maximum and minimum of $$L=\sqrt{1-x^2}+\sqrt{1-y^2}+\sqrt{1-z^2},$$

given that $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$?

I worked on some basic algebra, but it doesn't get me anywhere, so I'm stuck on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using lagrange multipliers $$ f(x,y,z) = \sqrt{1 - x^2} + \sqrt{1 - y^2} + \sqrt{1 -  z^2} $$ subject to $$ g(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1 = 0 $$

$$ F(x,y,z,\lambda) = f + \lambda g = \sqrt{1 - x^2} + \sqrt{1 - y^2} + \sqrt{1 -  z^2} + \lambda( x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1) $$

$$ F_x = \frac{-2x}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}} + 2\lambda x = 0 $$

$$ F_y = \frac{-2y}{2\sqrt{1-y^2}} + 2\lambda y = 0  $$

$$ F_z = \frac{-2z}{2\sqrt{1-z^2}} + 2\lambda z = 0  $$

$$ F_{\lambda} = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1 = 0 $$

now solve this system of equations :-)

Comment: please note the edit :-)

Answer (score 3):

**By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality**

$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{1-x^2}\le\sqrt{3\cdot(1-x^2+1-y^2-z^2)}=\sqrt{6}$$

By the other hand,we have
\begin{align*}
&\sqrt{1-x^2}+\sqrt{1-y^2}+\sqrt{1-z^2}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{y^2+z^2}+\sqrt{x^2+z^2}\\
&\ge\sqrt{0+y^2}+\sqrt{0+z^2}+\sqrt{y^2+z^2}\\
&=|y|+|z|+\sqrt{y^2+z^2}
\end{align*}

this problem since $y^2+z^2=1$,find the $|y|+|z|+1$ minum

let
$$|y|=a\ge 0,|z|=b\ge0, a^2+b^2=1$$
then
$$|y|+|z|+1=a+b+1=\cos{t}+\sin{t}+1=\sqrt{2}\sin{(t+\dfrac{\pi}{4})}+1\ge 2$$

Comment: In finding the minimum, why not set $y$ to be zero also, just the way you did $x$? In both cases, note $z$ changes to maintain the constraint. So this step isn't valid in general.

Comment: By the same argument you used in the "other hand" case, I can say things like $\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{1-x^2} \le \sqrt{1-0^2} + \sqrt{1-0^2} + \sqrt{1 - z^2} = 2$ as in this case $z = 1$, which is clearly absurd.

Comment: your mean is wrong ....

Comment: This problem is find the maxum and minmum.....

Comment: I mean $2 \le L \le \sqrt{6}$ is correct.  But your **method** for finding minimum is **wrong**.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to convert the equation in polar coordinates which will simplify the equation as $r=1$ meaning you only have two unknowns left to solve.